# Arduino ISR - multiple definitions of vector

Tags: c++, arduino, dmx512

I'm using a DMX library of four universes, [here](http://www.deskontrol.net/blog/arduino-four-universes-dmx-512-library/).

Using this library without any other libraries works perfectly fine. However, when also using the standard `SPI.h` lirary I get a conflict with ISR's in the folliwng lines of code:

**lib_dmx.ccp** (line 3)

```
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    ISR (USART_RX_vect)
    {
      ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0);
    }  
  #endif
#endif
```

**HardwareSerial.cpp** (line 2)

```
#if defined(USART_RX_vect)
  ISR(USART_RX_vect)
```

Now, I am rather unfamilier with the interrupt services with arduino's. The `HardwareSerial.cpp` is a Arduino core, so I presume I can't really change anything in this file.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

Removing the ISR and replacing it with a `serialEvent()` gives me the error *error: invalid use of void expression*. Without the void, `serialEvent()` isn't declared properly. Do I have to include a certain library?

**lib_dmx.ccp**

```
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    void serialEvent(){
        serialEvent(ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0));
    }
  #endif
#endif
```

**Update 2:**

**lib_dmx.cpp**

```
/***************************************************************************
*
* Title          : Arduino DMX512 library. 4 input/output universes.
* Version        : v 0.3 beta
* Last updated   : 07.07.2012
* Target         : Arduino mega 2560, Arduino mega 1280, Arduino nano (1 universe)  
* Author         : Toni Merino - merino.toni at gmail.com
* Web            : www.deskontrol.net/blog
*
* Based on ATmega8515 Dmx library written by Hendrik Hoelscher, www.hoelscher-hi.de
***************************************************************************

 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
 modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License 
 as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version2 of 
 the License, or (at your option) any later version. 

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU 
 General Public License for more details. 

 If you have no copy of the GNU General Public License, write to the 
 Free Software Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA. 

 For other license models, please contact the author.

;***************************************************************************/
#include "lib_dmx.h"
#include <SPI.h>

#if defined(USE_UART0)
  CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx0(0);
#endif
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  #if defined(USE_UART1)
    CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx1(1);
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART2)
    CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx2(2);
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART3)
    CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx3(3);
  #endif
#endif

// *************** DMX Transmision Initialisation ****************
void CArduinoDmx::init_tx(uint8_t mode)
{
  cli();          //disable interrupts
  stop_dmx();                         //stop uart
  dmx_mode = mode;
  set_speed(dmx_mode);

  if(control_pin != -1)
  {
    pinMode(control_pin,OUTPUT);        // max485 I/O control
    digitalWrite(control_pin, HIGH);    // set 485 as output
  }

  if(mUART == 0)
  {
    pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
    UBRR0H   = 0;
    UBRR0L   = speed_dmx;  
    UCSR0A  |= (1<<U2X0);
    UCSR0C  |= (3<<UCSZ00)|(1<<USBS0);
    UCSR0B  |= (1<<TXEN0) |(1<<TXCIE0);
    UDR0     = 0;                                     //start USART 0
  }
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  else if(mUART == 1)
  {
    pinMode(18, OUTPUT); 
    UBRR1H   = 0;
    UBRR1L   = speed_dmx;   
    UCSR1A  |= (1<<U2X1);
    UCSR1C  |= (3<<UCSZ10)|(1<<USBS1);
    UCSR1B  |= (1<<TXEN1) |(1<<TXCIE1);
    UDR1     = 0;                                     //start USART 1
  }
  else if(mUART == 2)
  {
    pinMode(16, OUTPUT); 
    UBRR2H   = 0;
    UBRR2L   = speed_dmx;   
    UCSR2A  |= (1<<U2X2);
    UCSR2C  |= (3<<UCSZ20)|(1<<USBS2);
    UCSR2B  |= (1<<TXEN2) |(1<<TXCIE2);
    UDR2     = 0;                                     //start USART 2
  }
  else if(mUART == 3)
  {
    pinMode(14, OUTPUT); 
    UBRR3H   = 0;
    UBRR3L   = speed_dmx;    
    UCSR3A  |= (1<<U2X3);
    UCSR3C  |= (3<<UCSZ30)|(1<<USBS3);
    UCSR3B  |= (1<<TXEN3) |(1<<TXCIE3);
    UDR3     = 0;                                     //start USART 3
  }
#endif

  gTxState = BREAK;                                     // start with break
  TxBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(tx_channels);     // allocate mem for buffer
  memset((uint8_t*)TxBuffer, 0, tx_channels);   // fill buffer with 0's
  sei();          //enable interrupts
}

// ************************ DMX Stop ***************************
void CArduinoDmx::stop_dmx()
{
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  if(mUART == 0)
  {
    UCSR0B &= ~((1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<TXCIE0) | (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0));
  }
  else if(mUART == 1)
  {
    UCSR1B &= ~((1<<RXCIE1) | (1<<TXCIE1) | (1<<RXEN1) | (1<<TXEN1));
  }
  else if(mUART == 2)
  {
    UCSR2B &= ~((1<<RXCIE2) | (1<<TXCIE2) | (1<<RXEN2) | (1<<TXEN2));
  }
  else if(mUART == 3)
  {
    UCSR3B &= ~((1<<RXCIE3) | (1<<TXCIE3) | (1<<RXEN3) | (1<<TXEN3));
  }
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  if(mUART == 0)
  {
    UCSR0B &= ~((1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<TXCIE0) | (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0));
  }
#endif
}

// *************** DMX Reception Initialisation ****************
void CArduinoDmx::init_rx(uint8_t mode)
{
  cli();          //disable interrupts
  stop_dmx();
  dmx_mode = mode;
  set_speed(dmx_mode);

  if(control_pin != -1)
  {
    pinMode(control_pin,OUTPUT);        //max485 I/O control
    digitalWrite(control_pin, LOW);     //set 485 as input
  }

  if(mUART == 0)
  {
    pinMode(0, INPUT); 
    UBRR0H   = 0;
    UBRR0L   = speed_dmx;
    UCSR0A  |= (1<<U2X0);
    UCSR0C  |= (3<<UCSZ00)|(1<<USBS0);
    UCSR0B  |= (1<<RXEN0) |(1<<RXCIE0);
  }
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  else if(mUART == 1)
  {
    pinMode(19, INPUT); 
    UBRR1H   = 0;
    UBRR1L   = speed_dmx;
    UCSR1A  |= (1<<U2X1);
    UCSR1C  |= (3<<UCSZ10)|(1<<USBS1);
    UCSR1B  |= (1<<RXEN1) |(1<<RXCIE1);
  }
  else if(mUART == 2)
  {
    pinMode(17, INPUT); 
    UBRR2H   = 0;
    UBRR2L   = speed_dmx;
    UCSR2A  |= (1<<U2X2); 
    UCSR2C  |= (3<<UCSZ20)|(1<<USBS2);
    UCSR2B  |= (1<<RXEN2) |(1<<RXCIE2);
  }
  else if(mUART == 3)
  {
    pinMode(15, INPUT); 
    UBRR3H   = 0;
    UBRR3L   = speed_dmx; 
    UCSR3A  |= (1<<U2X3);
    UCSR3C  |= (3<<UCSZ30)|(1<<USBS3);
    UCSR3B  |= (1<<RXEN3) |(1<<RXCIE3);
  }
#endif

  gRxState = IDLE;
  RxBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(rx_channels);   // allocate mem for buffer
  memset((uint8_t*)RxBuffer, 0, rx_channels); // fill buffer with 0's
  sei();          //enable interrupts
}

// *************** DMX Reception ISR ****************
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    ISR (SIG_USART0_RECV)
    {
      ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART1)
    ISR (SIG_USART1_RECV)
    {
      ArduinoDmx1.Process_ISR_RX(1);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART2)
    ISR (SIG_USART2_RECV)
    {
      ArduinoDmx2.Process_ISR_RX(2);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART3)
    ISR (SIG_USART3_RECV)
    {
      ArduinoDmx3.Process_ISR_RX(3);
    }
  #endif
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    /*ISR (USART_RX_vect)
    {
        ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0);
    }*/
    /*void serialEvent(){
        serialEvent(ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0));
    }*/  
  #endif
#endif

void CArduinoDmx::Process_ISR_RX(uint8_t rx_isr_number)
{
  if(rx_isr_number == 0)
  {
    USARTstate = UCSR0A;                  //get state
    RxByte     = UDR0;                //get data
    RxState    = gRxState;                    //just get once from SRAM!!!
    if (USARTstate &(1<<FE0))         //check for break
    {                   
      UCSR0A  &= ~(1<<FE0);                 //reset flag
      RxCount  = rx_address;                  //reset frame counter
      gRxState = BREAK;
    }
  }
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)

  else if(rx_isr_number == 1)
  {
    USARTstate = UCSR1A;                  //get state
    RxByte     = UDR1;                //get data
    RxState    = gRxState;                    //just get once from SRAM!!!
    if (USARTstate &(1<<FE1))         //check for break
    {                   
      UCSR1A  &= ~(1<<FE1);                 //reset flag
      RxCount  = rx_address;                  //reset frame counter
      gRxState = BREAK;
    }
  }
  else if(rx_isr_number == 2)
  {
    USARTstate = UCSR2A;                  //get state
    RxByte     = UDR2;                //get data
    RxState    = gRxState;                    //just get once from SRAM!!!
    if (USARTstate &(1<<FE2))         //check for break
    {                   
      UCSR2A  &= ~(1<<FE2);                 //reset flag
      RxCount  = rx_address;                  //reset frame counter
      gRxState = BREAK;
    }
  }
  else if(rx_isr_number == 3)
  {
    USARTstate = UCSR3A;                  //get state
    RxByte     = UDR3;                //get data
    RxState    = gRxState;                    //just get once from SRAM!!!
    if (USARTstate &(1<<FE3))         //check for break
    {                   
      UCSR3A  &= ~(1<<FE3);                 //reset flag
      RxCount  = rx_address;                  //reset frame counter
      gRxState = BREAK;
    }
  }
#endif

  if (RxState == BREAK)
  {
    if (RxByte == 0) 
    {
      gRxState = STARTB;                          //normal start code detected
      gRxPnt   = ((uint8_t*)RxBuffer + 1);
    }
    else 
      gRxState = IDLE;
  }
  else if (RxState == STARTB)
  {
    if (--RxCount == 0)                         //start address reached?
    {
      gRxState   = STARTADR;
      RxBuffer[0]= RxByte;
    }
  }
  else if (RxState == STARTADR)
  {
    RxPnt  = gRxPnt;
    *RxPnt = RxByte;
    if (++RxPnt >= (RxBuffer + rx_channels))    //all ch received?
    {
      gRxState= IDLE;
      if (*RXisrCallback) RXisrCallback(mUART);   // fire callback for read data
    }
    else 
    {
      gRxPnt = RxPnt;
    }
  }                         
}

// *************** DMX Transmision ISR ****************
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    ISR(SIG_USART0_TRANS)
    {
      ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_TX(0);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART1)
    ISR(SIG_USART1_TRANS)
    {
      ArduinoDmx1.Process_ISR_TX(1);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART2)
    ISR(SIG_USART2_TRANS)
    {
      ArduinoDmx2.Process_ISR_TX(2);
    }
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART3)
    ISR(SIG_USART3_TRANS)
    {
      ArduinoDmx3.Process_ISR_TX(3);
    }
  #endif
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  #if defined(USE_UART0)
    ISR(USART_TX_vect)
    {
      ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_TX(0);
    }
  #endif
#endif


void CArduinoDmx::Process_ISR_TX(uint8_t tx_isr_number)
{
  TxState = gTxState;

  if(tx_isr_number == 0)
  {
    if (TxState == TXBREAK) //BREAK + MAB
    {
      UBRR0H   = 0;
      UBRR0L   = speed_break;
      UDR0     = 0;                                 //send break
      gTxState = TXSTARTB;
    }
    else if (TxState == TXSTARTB)
    {
      UBRR0H   = 0;
      UBRR0L   = speed_dmx;
      UDR0     = 0;                                 //send start byte
      gTxState = TXDATA;
      gCurTxCh = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      #if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)
        delay_gap();
      #endif    
      CurTxCh = gCurTxCh;
      UDR0 = TxBuffer[CurTxCh++];               //send data
      if (CurTxCh == tx_channels)
      {
        if (*TXisrCallback) TXisrCallback(0); // fire callback for update data
        gTxState = TXBREAK;   // new break if all ch sent
      }
      else 
      {
        gCurTxCh = CurTxCh;
      }
    }
  }
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)

  else if(tx_isr_number == 1)
  {
    if (TxState == TXBREAK)
    {
      UBRR1H   = 0;
      UBRR1L   = speed_break;
      UDR1     = 0;                                 //send break
      gTxState = TXSTARTB;
    }
    else if (TxState == TXSTARTB)
    {
      UBRR1H   = 0;
      UBRR1L   = speed_dmx;
      UDR1     = 0;                                 //send start byte
      gTxState = TXDATA;
      gCurTxCh = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      #if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)
        delay_gap();
      #endif    
      CurTxCh = gCurTxCh;
      UDR1 = TxBuffer[CurTxCh++];               //send data
      if (CurTxCh == tx_channels)
      {
        if (*TXisrCallback) TXisrCallback(1); // fire callback for update data
        gTxState = TXBREAK;   // new break if all ch sent
      }
      else 
      {
        gCurTxCh = CurTxCh;
      }
    }
  }
  else if(tx_isr_number == 2)
  {
    if (TxState == TXBREAK)
    {
      UBRR2H   = 0;
      UBRR2L   = speed_break;
      UDR2     = 0;                                 //send break
      gTxState = TXSTARTB;
    }
    else if (TxState == TXSTARTB)
    {
      UBRR2H   = 0;
      UBRR2L   = speed_dmx;
      UDR2     = 0;                                 //send start byte
      gTxState = TXDATA;
      gCurTxCh = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      #if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)
        delay_gap();
      #endif   
      CurTxCh = gCurTxCh;
      UDR2 = TxBuffer[CurTxCh++];               //send data
      if (CurTxCh == tx_channels)
      {
        if (*TXisrCallback) TXisrCallback(2); // fire callback for update data
        gTxState = TXBREAK;   // new break if all ch sent
      }
      else 
      {
        gCurTxCh = CurTxCh;
      }
    }
  }
  else if(tx_isr_number == 3)
  {
    if (TxState == TXBREAK)
    {
      UBRR3H   = 0;
      UBRR3L   = speed_break;
      UDR3     = 0;                                 //send break
      gTxState = TXSTARTB;
    }
    else if (TxState == TXSTARTB)
    {
      UBRR3H   = 0;
      UBRR3L   = speed_dmx;
      UDR3     = 0;                                 //send start byte
      gTxState = TXDATA;
      gCurTxCh = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      #if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)
        delay_gap();
      #endif
      CurTxCh = gCurTxCh;
      UDR3 = TxBuffer[CurTxCh++];               //send data
      if (CurTxCh == tx_channels)
      {
        if (*TXisrCallback) TXisrCallback(3); // fire callback for update data
        gTxState = TXBREAK;   // new break if all ch sent
      }
      else 
      {
        gCurTxCh = CurTxCh;
      }
    }
  }
#endif
}

void CArduinoDmx::set_speed(uint8_t mode)
{
  if(mode == 0)
  {
    speed_dmx   = DMX_512;    // DMX-512  (250 kbaud - 512 channels) Standard USITT DMX-512
    speed_break = BREAK_512;
  }
  else if(mode == 1)
  {
    speed_dmx   = DMX_1024;   // DMX-1024 (500 kbaud - 1024 channels) Completely non standard, but usefull ;)
    speed_break = BREAK_1024;
  }
  else if(mode == 2)
  {
    speed_dmx   = DMX_2048;   // DMX-2048 (1000 kbaud - 2048 channels) Used by manufacturers as DMX1000K, DMX-4x or DMX-1M ???
    speed_break = BREAK_2048;
  }  
}

#if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)

void CArduinoDmx::delay_gap() // rare cases of equipment non full DMX-512 compliant, need this
{
  if(dmx_mode == 0)
  {
    _delay_us(IBG_512);
  }
  else if(dmx_mode == 1)
  {
    _delay_us(IBG_1024);
  }
  else if(dmx_mode == 2)
  {
    _delay_us(IBG_2048);
  }
}
#endif
```

**lib_dmx.h**

```
/***************************************************************************
*
* Title          : Arduino DMX512 library. 4 input/output universes.
* Version        : v 0.3 beta
* Last updated   : 07.07.2012
* Target         : Arduino mega 2560, Arduino mega 1280, Arduino nano (1 universe)  
* Author         : Toni Merino - merino.toni at gmail.com
* Web            : www.deskontrol.net/blog
*
* Based on ATmega8515 Dmx library written by Hendrik Hoelscher, www.hoelscher-hi.de
***************************************************************************
 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
 modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License 
 as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version2 of 
 the License, or (at your option) any later version. 

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU 
 General Public License for more details. 

 If you have no copy of the GNU General Public License, write to the 
 Free Software Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA. 

 For other license models, please contact the author.

;***************************************************************************/
#ifndef __INC_DMX_H
#define __INC_DMX_H

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#if ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
   #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

//#define        USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY     // rare cases of equipment non full DMX-512 compliant, need this

// *** comment UARTs not used ***
#define        USE_UART0
//#define        USE_UART1
//#define        USE_UART2
//#define        USE_UART3

// New DMX modes *** EXPERIMENTAL ***
#define        DMX512            (0)    // DMX-512 (250 kbaud - 512 channels) Standard USITT DMX-512
#define        DMX1024           (1)    // DMX-1024 (500 kbaud - 1024 channels) Completely non standard - TESTED ok
#define        DMX2048           (2)    // DMX-2048 (1000 kbaud - 2048 channels) called by manufacturers DMX1000K, DMX 4x or DMX 1M ???

// DMX-512  (250 kbaud - 512 channels) Standard USITT DMX-512
#define        IBG_512           (10)                      // interbyte gap [us]
#define        DMX_512           ((F_CPU/(250000*8))-1)    // 250 kbaud
#define        BREAK_512         ( F_CPU/(100000*8))       // 90.9 kbaud

// DMX-1024 (500 kbaud - 1024 channels) Completely non standard
#define        IBG_1024          (5)                       // interbyte gap [us]
#define        DMX_1024          ((F_CPU/(500000*8))-1)    // 500 kbaud
#define        BREAK_1024        ( F_CPU/(200000*8))       // 181.8 kbaud

// DMX-2048 (1000 kbaud - 2048 channels) Non standard, but used by manufacturers as DMX1000K or DMX-4x or DMX 1M ???
#define        IBG_2048          (2)                       // interbyte gap [us] + nop's to reach 2.5 uS
#define        DMX_2048          ((F_CPU/(1000000*8))-1)   // 1000 kbaud
#define        BREAK_2048        ( F_CPU/(400000*8))       // 363.6 kbaud

// Inline assembly: do nothing for one clock cycle.
#define        nop()             __asm__ __volatile__("nop")

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  #if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
    #if defined(USE_UART0)
      void SIG_USART0_RECV  (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
      void SIG_USART0_TRANS (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART1)
      void SIG_USART1_RECV  (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
      void SIG_USART1_TRANS (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART2)  
      void SIG_USART2_RECV  (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
      void SIG_USART2_TRANS (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART3)  
      void SIG_USART3_RECV  (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
      void SIG_USART3_TRANS (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
    #endif
  #elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
    #if defined(USE_UART0)
      void USART_RX_vect    (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
      void USART_TX_vect    (void) __attribute__((__always_inline__));
    #endif
  #endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif

class CArduinoDmx 
{ 
  #if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
    #if defined(USE_UART0)
      friend void SIG_USART0_RECV  (void);
      friend void SIG_USART0_TRANS (void);
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART1)
      friend void SIG_USART1_RECV  (void);
      friend void SIG_USART1_TRANS (void);
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART2)  
      friend void SIG_USART2_RECV  (void);
      friend void SIG_USART2_TRANS (void);
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_UART3)  
      friend void SIG_USART3_RECV  (void);
      friend void SIG_USART3_TRANS (void);
    #endif
  #elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
    #if defined(USE_UART0)
      friend void USART_RX_vect    (void);
      friend void USART_TX_vect    (void);
    #endif
  #endif

public:
   enum {IDLE, BREAK, STARTB, STARTADR};     // RX DMX states
   enum {TXBREAK, TXSTARTB, TXDATA};         // TX DMX states

   volatile uint8_t    *RxBuffer;            // array of RX DMX values
   volatile uint8_t    *TxBuffer;            // array of TX DMX values

private:
   uint8_t     gRxState;
   uint8_t    *gRxPnt;
   uint8_t     IndicatorCount;
   uint8_t     USARTstate;      
   uint8_t     RxByte;     
   uint8_t     RxState;
   uint8_t     mUART;
   uint8_t     gTxState;
   uint16_t    RxCount;
   uint16_t    gCurTxCh;        
   uint16_t    rx_channels;                  // rx channels number
   uint16_t    tx_channels;                  // tx channels number
   uint16_t    rx_address;                   // rx start address
   uint16_t    tx_address;                   // tx start address
   int8_t      rx_led;                       // rx indicator led pin
   int8_t      tx_led;                       // tx indicator led pin
   int8_t      control_pin;                  // max485 input/output selection pin
   uint8_t     dmx_mode;                     // Standard USITT DMX512 = 0, non standard DMX1024 = 1, non standard DMX2048 (DMX1000K) = 2
   uint8_t     speed_dmx;
   uint8_t     speed_break;
   uint16_t    CurTxCh;
   uint8_t     TxState;
   uint8_t    *RxPnt;

#if defined(USE_INTERBYTE_DELAY)   
   void        delay_gap          ();
#endif

public:
   void        stop_dmx           ();
   void        set_speed          (uint8_t mode);
   void        set_control_pin    (int8_t  pin)        { control_pin     = pin;      }
   void        init_rx            (uint8_t mode);  // Standard USITT DMX512 = 0, non standard DMX1024 = 1, non standard DMX2048 (DMX1000K) = 2
   void        set_rx_address     (uint16_t address)   { rx_address      = address;  }
   void        set_rx_channels    (uint16_t channels)  { rx_channels     = channels; }
   void        init_tx            (uint8_t mode);  // Standard USITT DMX512 = 0, non standard DMX1024 = 1, non standard DMX2048 (DMX1000K) = 2
   void        set_tx_address     (uint16_t address)   { tx_address      = address;  }
   void        set_tx_channels    (uint16_t channels)  { tx_channels     = channels; }

   void        attachTXInterrupt  (void (*isr)(uint8_t uart))      { TXisrCallback   = isr; }   // register the user TX callback
   void        attachRXInterrupt  (void (*isr)(uint8_t uart))      { RXisrCallback   = isr; }   // register the user RX callback

   void        (*TXisrCallback)   (uint8_t uart);
   void        (*RXisrCallback)   (uint8_t uart);

   inline void Process_ISR_RX     (uint8_t  rx_isr_number);
   inline void Process_ISR_TX     (uint8_t  tx_isr_number);

public:
   CArduinoDmx                    (uint8_t uart)       { rx_address      = 1; 
                                                         rx_channels     = 8;
                                                         tx_address      = 1; 
                                                         tx_channels     = 8;
                                                         mUART           = uart; }

};

#if defined(USE_UART0)
  extern CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx0;
#endif
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  #if defined(USE_UART1)
    extern CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx1;
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART2)
    extern CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx2;
  #endif
  #if defined(USE_UART3)
    extern CArduinoDmx ArduinoDmx3;
  #endif
#endif

#endif
```

**myfile.ino**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
//#include <EthernetUdp.h>
#include <lib_dmx.h>

#define DMX512  (0)

byte mac[] = { 0xDD, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(10,0,0,2); // TODO: assign ip address from DHCP
unsigned int multicastPort = 8888;
IPAddress multicastIp(239,0,0,57);

char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];

//EthernetUDP Udp;

int sensorValue = 0;
int ledState = 0;
int DMXPin = 0;

void setup() {

  // DMX
  ArduinoDmx0.set_control_pin(DMXPin);
  ArduinoDmx0.set_rx_channels(1);
  ArduinoDmx0.set_tx_channels(5);
  ArduinoDmx0.init_tx(DMX512);

  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
  //Udp.beginMulti( multicastIp, multicastPort );
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  /*int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if(packetSize){
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i =0; i < 4; i++){
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3){
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    Udp.read(packetBuffer,UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer[0]);

    ArduinoDmx0.TxBuffer[0] = (int)packetBuffer;
  }*/
}
```

This library allows multiple universes for DMX, though I'm only using the first one now (which is why in the .h file some of them are escaped out). In the myfile.ino I removed certain things because I'm also implementing a UDP multicast library (modified standard Ethernet library).

Answer (score 1):

you can delete that ISR from the lib_dmx and put ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0); into [serialEvent()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please take a look at my updated question since I'm experiencing some issues.

Comment: i fear you have to put serialEvent() in the .ino file and not in library.

Comment: I have put it in the `lib_dmx.cpp` file, on the exact same place as where he `ISR` was.

Comment: but serialEvent() is a trick done by the IDE, and it is not so feasible. It must be in the .ino, there you can call your lib. I know, it's not very good solution but altrnative is to modify the IDE lib

Comment: My bad - I misread your remark. Writing the `serialEvent()` function in the .ino file halas gives me an error: `undefined reference to 'CArduinoDmx::Process_ISR_RX(unsigned char)'`

Comment: because ArduinoDmx0 is inside the class lib_dmx, you have to make it public and add the name of the object, somethink like
void serialEvent(){name.ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0);}
where name is the name of the object lib_dmx (full code would help)

Comment: I added the source codes (rather big), but searching for the code I gave should quickly give the issues.

Comment: serialEvent(){ArduinoDmx0.Process_ISR_RX(0);}
should work, if not, in lib_dmx.h add public:void Process_ISR_RX(uint8_t rx_isr_number); (that way the method is public)